# select and unselect not working for dynamically created checkbox in js

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created dynamically in java script checkbox tree using bootstrap js and css. Select and unselect does not working: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRPa9.png)

In the second picture is the html created dynamically from js: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMWw3.png)
If I copy this and create in the html it is working. 
How to create dynamically check box tree?

```js
$(function() {

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(checkboxChanged);

  function checkboxChanged() {
    var $this = $(this),
        checked = $this.prop("checked"),
        container = $this.parent(),
        siblings = container.siblings();

    container.find('input[type="checkbox"]')
    .prop({
        indeterminate: false,
        checked: checked
    })
    .siblings('label')
    .removeClass('custom-checked custom-unchecked custom-indeterminate')
    .addClass(checked ? 'custom-checked' : 'custom-unchecked');

    checkSiblings(container, checked);
  }

  function checkSiblings($el, checked) {
    var parent = $el.parent().parent(),
        all = true,
        indeterminate = false;

    $el.siblings().each(function() {
      return all = ($(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked") === checked);
    });

    if (all && checked) {
      parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .prop({
          indeterminate: false,
          checked: checked
      })
      .siblings('label')
      .removeClass('custom-checked custom-unchecked custom-indeterminate')
      .addClass(checked ? 'custom-checked' : 'custom-unchecked');

      checkSiblings(parent, checked);
    } 
    else if (all && !checked) {
      indeterminate = parent.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0;

      parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .prop("checked", checked)
      .prop("indeterminate", indeterminate)
      .siblings('label')
      .removeClass('custom-checked custom-unchecked custom-indeterminate')
      .addClass(indeterminate ? 'custom-indeterminate' : (checked ? 'custom-checked' : 'custom-unchecked'));

      checkSiblings(parent, checked);
    } 
    else {
      $el.parents("li").children('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .prop({
          indeterminate: true,
          checked: false
      })
      .siblings('label')
      .removeClass('custom-checked custom-unchecked custom-indeterminate')
      .addClass('custom-indeterminate');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#page-wrap {
  margin: auto 0;
}

.treeview {
  margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
}

ul { 
  list-style: none;
}

.treeview li {
  background: url(http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/images/treeview-default-line.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
  padding: 2px 0 2px 16px;
}

.treeview > li:first-child > label {
  /* style for the root element - IE8 supports :first-child
  but not :last-child ..... */
  
}

.treeview li.last {
  background-position: 0 -1766px;
}

.treeview li > input {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  /* hide the inputs but keep them in the layout with events (use opacity) */
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* internet explorer */ 
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0)"; /*IE8*/
}

.treeview li > label {
  background: url(https://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_custom-forms/gr_custom-inputs.png) 0 -1px no-repeat;
  /* move left to cover the original checkbox area */
  margin-left: -20px;
  /* pad the text to make room for image */
  padding-left: 20px;
}

/* Unchecked styles */

.treeview .custom-unchecked {
  background-position: 0 -1px;
}
.treeview .custom-unchecked:hover {
  background-position: 0 -21px;
}

/* Checked styles */

.treeview .custom-checked { 
  background-position: 0 -81px;
}
.treeview .custom-checked:hover { 
  background-position: 0 -101px; 
}

/* Indeterminate styles */

.treeview .custom-indeterminate { 
  background-position: 0 -141px; 
}
.treeview .custom-indeterminate:hover { 
  background-position: 0 -121px; 
}
```

```html
<body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini" style="height: auto; min-height: 100%;">
   
    <!-- changing values in row -->
    <input id="rowNumber" class="form-control " type="hidden">

    <div class="wrapper" style="height: auto; min-height: 100%; background-color: #ECEFF4;">
        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
           
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <!-- /.box -->
                    <div class="box">
                        <!-- /.box-header -->
                        <div class="box-body">   

                            <button onclick="addCheckBox()">add</button>
                            <input id="check" name="checkBoxes">   
                            <div id="page-wrap">
                                <ul class="treeview">                                    
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="short" id="short">
                                        <label for="short" class="custom-unchecked">Short Things</label>

                                        <ul id="cc">
                                           
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                            </div>                            
                        </div>                       
                        <!-- /.box-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </section>
        <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addCheckBox() {

        var listElement = document.getElementById('cc');
        var check_value = new Array();
        check_value[1] = "Yellow";
        check_value[2] = "Red";
        check_value[3] = "Green";

        var li, checkbox, label, br, a;

        var title = document.getElementById('check').value;

        for (var i = 1; i <= title; i++) {
            li = document.createElement("li");
            if (i == title)
            {
                li.className = "last";
            }
            checkbox = document.createElement("input");
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            checkbox.name = "short-" + i;
            checkbox.id = "short-" + i;
            label = document.createElement("label");
            label.htmlFor = "short-" + i;
            label.className = "custom-unchecked";
            label.setAttribute("class", "custom-unchecked");
            label.innerHTML = check_value[i];

            li.innerHTML += checkbox.outerHTML + label.outerHTML;
            listElement.appendChild(li);

            /*li.appendChild(checkbox);
            //li.appendChild(label);
            listElement.appendChild(li);
            listElement.appendChild(checkbox);
            listElement.appendChild(label); */
        }
    }  
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alx-lark says, The issue you are encountering is that you are binding on change event on initial page load, but the way the event binding works, any *subsequent* checkbox elements that are added to the page later on will not be bound. The solution mentioned in his answer - unbinding on ALL checkboxes and then rebinding on ALL checkboxes, including the ones most recently added, should work.

You could also bind on the individual checkbox as you add it, OR you could bind higher up on an element that always does exist, like the `document`

This is probably the easiest change to make, changing the line

`$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(checkboxChanged)` 
to 
`$(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', checkboxChanged);`

This is called **event delegation** and you can read about it here: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```js
 function checkboxChanged() {
    var $this = $(this),
        checked = $this.prop("checked"),
        container = $this.parent(),
        siblings = container.siblings();

    container.find('input[type="checkbox"]')
    .prop({
        indeterminate: false,
        checked: checked
    })
    .siblings('label')
    .removeClass('custom-checked custom-unchecked custom-indeterminate')
    .addClass(checked ? 'custom-checked' : 'custom-unchecked');

    checkSiblings(container, checked);
  }

  function checkSiblings($el, checked) {
    var parent = $el.parent().parent(),
        all = true,
        indeterminate = false;

    $el.siblings().each(function() {
      return all = ($(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked") === checked);
    });

    if (all && checked) {
      parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .prop({
          indeterminate: false,
          checked: checked
      })
      .siblings('label')
      .removeClass('custom-checked custom-unchecked custom-indeterminate')
      .addClass(checked ? 'custom-checked' : 'custom-unchecked');

      checkSiblings(parent, checked);
    } 
    else if (all && !checked) {
      indeterminate = parent.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0;

      parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .prop("checked", checked)
      .prop("indeterminate", indeterminate)
      .siblings('label')
      .removeClass('custom-checked custom-unchecked custom-indeterminate')
      .addClass(indeterminate ? 'custom-indeterminate' : (checked ? 'custom-checked' : 'custom-unchecked'));

      checkSiblings(parent, checked);
    } 
    else {
      $el.parents("li").children('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .prop({
          indeterminate: true,
          checked: false
      })
      .siblings('label')
      .removeClass('custom-checked custom-unchecked custom-indeterminate')
      .addClass('custom-indeterminate');
    }
  }

$(function() {

  $(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', checkboxChanged);

  
});
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#page-wrap {
  margin: auto 0;
}

.treeview {
  margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
}

ul { 
  list-style: none;
}

.treeview li {
  background: url(http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/images/treeview-default-line.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
  padding: 2px 0 2px 16px;
}

.treeview > li:first-child > label {
  /* style for the root element - IE8 supports :first-child
  but not :last-child ..... */
  
}

.treeview li.last {
  background-position: 0 -1766px;
}

.treeview li > input {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  /* hide the inputs but keep them in the layout with events (use opacity) */
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* internet explorer */ 
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0)"; /*IE8*/
}

.treeview li > label {
  background: url(https://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_custom-forms/gr_custom-inputs.png) 0 -1px no-repeat;
  /* move left to cover the original checkbox area */
  margin-left: -20px;
  /* pad the text to make room for image */
  padding-left: 20px;
}

/* Unchecked styles */

.treeview .custom-unchecked {
  background-position: 0 -1px;
}
.treeview .custom-unchecked:hover {
  background-position: 0 -21px;
}

/* Checked styles */

.treeview .custom-checked { 
  background-position: 0 -81px;
}
.treeview .custom-checked:hover { 
  background-position: 0 -101px; 
}

/* Indeterminate styles */

.treeview .custom-indeterminate { 
  background-position: 0 -141px; 
}
.treeview .custom-indeterminate:hover { 
  background-position: 0 -121px; 
}
```

```html
<body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini" style="height: auto; min-height: 100%;">
   
    <!-- changing values in row -->
    <input id="rowNumber" class="form-control " type="hidden">

    <div class="wrapper" style="height: auto; min-height: 100%; background-color: #ECEFF4;">
        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
           
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <!-- /.box -->
                    <div class="box">
                        <!-- /.box-header -->
                        <div class="box-body">   

                            <button onclick="addCheckBox()">add</button>
                            <input id="check" name="checkBoxes">   
                            <div id="page-wrap">
                                <ul class="treeview">                                    
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="short" id="short">
                                        <label for="short" class="custom-unchecked">Short Things</label>

                                        <ul id="cc">
                                           
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                            </div>                            
                        </div>                       
                        <!-- /.box-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </section>
        <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addCheckBox() {

        var listElement = document.getElementById('cc');
        var check_value = new Array();
        check_value[1] = "Yellow";
        check_value[2] = "Red";
        check_value[3] = "Green";

        var li, checkbox, label, br, a;

        var title = document.getElementById('check').value;

        for (var i = 1; i <= title; i++) {
            li = document.createElement("li");
            if (i == title)
            {
                li.className = "last";
            }
            checkbox = document.createElement("input");
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            checkbox.name = "short-" + i;
            checkbox.id = "short-" + i;
            label = document.createElement("label");
            label.htmlFor = "short-" + i;
            label.className = "custom-unchecked";
            label.setAttribute("class", "custom-unchecked");
            label.innerHTML = check_value[i];

            li.innerHTML += checkbox.outerHTML + label.outerHTML;
            listElement.appendChild(li);

            /*li.appendChild(checkbox);
            //li.appendChild(label);
            listElement.appendChild(li);
            listElement.appendChild(checkbox);
            listElement.appendChild(label); */
        }
    }  
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

From code point of view, all works correctly.

1. Event attached to created DOM elements after page loaded
2. You progamarly by clicking on Add button add new DOM elements.
3. So you should detach old events(to reduce memory leaks) and create new one.

In few words in your `addCheckBox()` function after creating new elements you should add:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').off('change'); // detach event
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', checkboxChanged); // add new event
```

Answer (score 0):

for me I had to target the container after document

```
$(document).on('change', '.input-container input[class^=open-all]', function(e) {
//console.log(e);
if (e.target !== this)
return;

if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    //true
    switchStatus = $(this).is(':checked');
}
else {
    // flase
    switchStatus = $(this).is(':checked');
}
});
```